# How to make a box with a tex at the corner of it?

Tags: boxes

[image]

How can i do following boxed text and also a boxed text with a text at the corner it ?

Please consider "lecture 1" is also a text. I want to write there my lecture number. That's why i keep it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with TikZ if you want, e.g.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text width=10cm,draw,inner sep=1em](mybox) {Another text here};
\node[anchor=west,fill=white,xshift=0.5em] at (mybox.north west){\textsc{Lecture} 1}; %This line is optional, remove it to get your first box without text on the edge.
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]